# Does $f \in L^1([0,T]; S'(\mathbb R^n))$ define a $(1+n)$-dimensional distribution?

Tags: linear-pde, schwartz-distributions, tempered-distributions

Let $f : [0,T] \rightarrow S'(\mathbb R^n)$ be a family of tempered distributions satisfying

$$\langle f(t), \phi \rangle \in L^1([0,T])$$

for any Schwartz function $\phi \in S(\mathbb R^n)$.

Does $f$ define a $(1+n)$-dimensional tempered distribution ? More precisely, is

$$(\star) \int_0^T \langle f(t), \phi(t) \rangle dt, \ \phi \in S(\mathbb R^{1+n})$$

a well-defined tempered distribution (or at least, just a distribution) ?

If not, what if we require stronger assumptions such as $C^0$ instead of $L^1$ ?

I'm learning about solving PDEs in tempered distribution space and I cannot quite understand the meaning of, say, the PDE

$$\partial_t f + v \cdot \nabla f = g, \ t \in [0,T]$$

With initial data $f(0) = f_0$. The assumptions on $g$, $f$ are usually of the same nature as the above condition on $f$.

Any help or reference is appreciated !

EDIT 1 :

I've a partial answer to my question.

According to Schwartz kernel theorem, there exists a unique tempered distribution $\hat{f} \in S'(\mathbb R^{1+n})$ such that
$$\langle \hat{f}, a \otimes b \rangle = \int_0^T \langle f(t), b \rangle a(t) dt$$
for any $a \in S(\mathbb R)$ and $b \in S(\mathbb R^n)$. Well, not exactly. We have to prove first that $b \mapsto \langle f(t), b \rangle$ is a continuous map from $S(\mathbb R^d)$ to $L^1(I)$.

Does ($\star$) make sense as a Lebesgue integral and is $\hat{f}$ given by ($\star$) ?

EDIT 2 :

I've another partial answer to my question.

If we require $C^0$ instead of $L^1$, then it is a consequence of Banach-Steinhaus that $t \mapsto \langle f(t), \phi(t) \rangle$ is continuous. Hence, integral ($\star$) makes sense.

This is proved in "Eléments de distributions et d'équations aux dérivées partielles" by Claude Zuily.

Is there a similar argument in the $L^1$-case ?

EDIT 3 :

I've also asked the question on [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4182646/if-langle-ut-phi-rangle-in-l1-forall-phi-in-s-bbb-rd-does-la)